# Update to Easy Slider 1.7 made all my JQuery code stop working

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty novice as a JQuery user goes. I've got some experience implementing different plugins but would be lost trying to customize my own.

I can't share the exact site details with you due to a NDA, so I hope someone can give me a little help. I've got a project due today (Just HTML/CSS/JQuery).

It has a lightbox, show/hide login menu and a slider is [Easy Slider 1.5](http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding). Everything was working together, until I attempted to update to Easy Slider 1.7 (see link on same page, I'm too new to post more than 1 link). When I did so, JQuery stopped working for all the plugins. I've attempted to revert back to the original state, by undoing my work (didn't do much), ad JQuery remains broken.

Firebug Error Console shared no errors. I can't find anything in the code no matter how hard I look at it.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this JQuery problem? Delivery is supposed to be tonight for the project.

EDIT:
Generic header info:

```
<!-- Global Style Sheet -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

<!-- Cufon -->

<script src="cufon/cufon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="cufon/gotham_325-gotham_350.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- jQuery Javascript -->

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".signin").click(function(e) {          
                e.preventDefault();
                $("fieldset#signin_menu").toggle();
                $(".signin").toggleClass("menu-open");
            });

            $("fieldset#signin_menu").mouseup(function() {
                return false
            });
            $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
                if($(e.target).parent("a.signin").length==0) {
                    $(".signin").removeClass("menu-open");
                    $("fieldset#signin_menu").hide();
                }
            });         

        });
</script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
      $('#forgot_username_link').tipsy({gravity: 'w'});   
    });
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/easySlider1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider();
}); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".regbox").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:270, innerHeight:270});
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you confirm jquery works by commenting out everything but the script element invoking it and doing a really simple function like : `alert($("body"))`?

Comment: Can you post the <script> tags you use to bring in jQuery and plugins?  Can you verify that none of them is returning 404?  (i.e. all JS links are valid).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand 100% basically only the call to the JQuery .js file, and a script with the alert code you specified in the header?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Can you post some of the html up? Even if you change like names or something it might help.

Comment: I could post the HTML, but none of it has changed from the previous working version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probable cause for your issue is that there's an exception thrown by a piece of script either before jQuery is loaded or before `$(document).ready()` call is made.

Start from the following code and include pieces of yours one by one until you locate the offending one:

```
<!-- jQuery Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            window.alert("jQuery works!");          
        });
</script>
```

*Side note*: why do you have two separate functions attached to `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: JQuery "works" with all my code included. Side note: Great question, I hadn't noticed it yet. Interestingly, condensing my $(document).ready() code made just the lightbox operable again, while the original slider and dropdown show/hide menu remain not working.